# I don't know whats wrong with this Android Studio project. Task: complete app that calculates quadratic equation

Tags: java, android

Task:

Download projects from the [link](https://github.com/myitschool-book/HomeWork.2.4.1). Open the HomeWork.2.4.1 project in android studio and modify MainActivity.java so that your application solves a quadratic equation like a*x*x+b*x+c=0.

Input data: three fields for entering real numbers - coefficients a, b, c

Answer: one real root, or two real roots separated by a space, or the word **any** (for any roots), or the word **none** (if there are no roots) should be displayed.

Example: input -2, 2, 0 output 1.0, 0.0

After you have finished the application, right click on the APP and select Run 'All Test'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4p8Y.png)

After checking, a message similar to the following will be displayed:

**YOUR RESULT: -1.618034, -3**

I don't know what is wrong. I writed OnClick{SolveEquation} but after click on button app fall down. What is wrong? Equation don't solve.

My code:

```
package ru.samsung.itschool.book;

import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void OnClick(){ // when click on the button
        solveEquation();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void solveEquation() { // solver
        double a = Double.parseDouble( ((EditText)
                findViewById(R.id.a)).getText().toString());
        double b = Double.parseDouble( ((EditText)
                findViewById(R.id.b)).getText().toString());
        double c = Double.parseDouble( ((EditText)
                findViewById(R.id.c)).getText().toString());
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

        double d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        double root1 = 0;
        double root2 = 0;
        if (d >= 0) {
            root1 = ((-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a));
            root2 = ((-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a));
        }
        result.setText("" + String.valueOf(root1) + String.valueOf(root2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a good time to re-read about the `@Override` annotation...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.